# Update the pager info in Kendo Grid pager

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Hi I want to update the pagerinfo of Kendo UI.

[image]

It was attained in jQuery by above. How Can I update the same in Angular.
I'm seeing the below options but nothing helps.

[image]

Can anyone help me in here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Grid pager template to customize the content, layout and formatting of the displayed information:

[Grid Pager Template](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/PagerTemplateDirective/)

All relevant variables like total, pageSize, skip, etc., are available in the template.

Apply custom formatting in the template or utilize the [Kendo Intl formatNumber function](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/internationalization/parsing-and-formatting/#toc-number-formatting) to format the desired values.